# Why does the min attribute stops affecting the html5 date picker if it goes beyond this year?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, frontend, arrow-functions

I have dynamically set two date inputs to pick dates based on current date in the first input(start_date), and based on what is selected in first input for the second input(end_date). The fields seem to update just well when dates are picked, until when the next date has to be in the following year, just when date picker in end_date stops respondig to min atrribute. I am testing my work in chrome browser. Can someone show me how to go around this one? Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="toMyStylesheets"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="toMyStylesheets"/>

    <title>MyTitle</title>
</head>
<body>

  <input type="date" name="start_date" id="start_date" />
  <input type="date" name="end_date" id="end_date" disabled />

</body>
</html>
```

And below is my JavaScript:

```
let startDate = document.getElementById('start_date');
let endDate = document.getElementById('end_date');

// Enable endDate if startDate is filled, as well as set minimum dates
let currentDate = new Date();
let dd = currentDate.getDate();
let mm = currentDate.getMonth()+1; // January is [0] so I added 1 to get the right month.
let yy = currentDate.getFullYear();

let today = yy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;

$(document).ready(() => {
  startDate.setAttribute("min", today);
});

startDate.oninput = () => {
  if (startDate.value.length > 0) {
    endDate.disabled = false;

    let fullSelectedDate = new Date(startDate.value);
    fullSelectedDate.setDate(fullSelectedDate.getDate() + 1); // Updating selected day to following day

    let selectedDd = fullSelectedDate.getDate();
    let selectedMm = fullSelectedDate.getMonth() +1;
    let selectedYy = fullSelectedDate.getFullYear();

    let nextDay = selectedYy+'-'+selectedMm+'-'+selectedDd;

    endDate.setAttribute("min", nextDay);

  } else {
    endDate.disabled = true;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  let startDate = document.getElementById('start_date');
  let endDate = document.getElementById('end_date');

  // Enable endDate if startDate is filled, as well as set minimum dates
  let currentDate = new Date();
  let dd = currentDate.getDate();
  let mm = currentDate.getMonth() + 1; // January is [0] so I added 1 to get the right month.
  let yy = currentDate.getFullYear();
      
  if(dd < 10) {
    dd = "0" + dd.toString();
  };

  if(mm < 10) {
    mm = "0" + mm.toString();
  };

  let today = yy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
  
  startDate.setAttribute("min", today);

  startDate.oninput = () => {
    if (startDate.value.length > 0) {
      endDate.disabled = false;

      let fullSelectedDate = new Date(startDate.value);
      fullSelectedDate.setDate(fullSelectedDate.getDate() + 1); // Updating selected day to following day

      let selectedDd = fullSelectedDate.getDate();
      let selectedMm = fullSelectedDate.getMonth() + 1;
      let selectedYy = fullSelectedDate.getFullYear();
      
      if(selectedDd < 10) {
        selectedDd = "0" + selectedDd.toString();
      };
      
      if(selectedMm < 10) {
        selectedMm = "0" + selectedMm.toString();
      };

      let nextDay = selectedYy + '-' + selectedMm + '-' + selectedDd;
      
      endDate.setAttribute("min", nextDay);

    } else {
      endDate.disabled = true;
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="toMyStylesheets"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="toMyStylesheets"/>

    <title>MyTitle</title>
</head>
<body>

  <input type="date" name="start_date" id="start_date" />
  <input type="date" name="end_date" id="end_date" disabled />

</body>
</html>
```

The reason the `min` attribute on `end_date` was not working was because it was not strictly in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. For example, if you set `start_date` to be 2020-12-31, `nextDay` has a value of '2021-1-1', which gets ignored in the `min` attribute. In the code above, a few simple `if` statements are added to convert the '1' values to '01' so that `nextDay` becomes '2021-01-01'.

Comment: Thank you so much #sbgib, even for the explanation on the root cause of my trouble! Your solution works like magic.

Comment: @KlemLloydMwenya no worries, I'm glad it worked for you :)